# MonoTouch add footer

Tags: xamarin.ios, table-footer

I am trying to add a Footer view with button in my table view. I found this code online

```
public override UIView GetViewForFooter(UITableView tableView, int sectionIndex)
{
    // Write a method to get the proper Section via the sectionIndex
    var section = GetSection(sectionIndex);
if (section != null)
{
    if (section.FooterView == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(section.FooterText))
    {
             // Create your FooterView here 
        section.FooterView = CreateFooterView(tableView, section.FooterText);
    }

    return section.FooterView;
}

return null;
}
```

I dont know what **GetSection** method is? I am having error "The name GetSection does not exist in the current context" .

I couldn't find any proper documentation on MonoTouch site as well.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: GetSection is probably a method you're suppose to write yourself, or a method that is implemented somewhere else in the sample you have found.

Comment: I agree that i have to write GetSection method but i dont know what should i write in it. Other worlds what parameters it takes and what it returns.

Comment: We're missing some context here. Are you using MonoTouch.Dialog? Where have you found the example?

Comment: I am not using MonoTouch.Dialog. I guess it is related to MonoTouch.Dialog, right? I wanna do it without MonoTouch.Dialog....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code you have is probably a MonoTouch.Dialog example. If you're not using MonoTouch.Dialog, simply return an appropriate UIView from this method. Something like:

```
public override UIView GetViewForFooter(UITableView tableView, int sectionIndex) {
    var myFooter = new UIView(); // Or some other class extending UIView, depending on what you want to do
    // Add SubViews and style the view
    return myFooter;
}
```

If you have more than one section in the table view, you can create different footers for each section by taking the `sectionIndex` parameter into consideration. For more information, check the [documentation](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UITableViewDelegate.GetViewForFooter%28MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView%2cSystem.Int32%29)